# syntax Error in Mail::send Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, swiftmailer

I'm not sure why I keep on getting this simple error. The error is saying I should not have a `;` on that line.

> syntax error, unexpected ';'

With my below code I get no errors:

```
Mail::send('emails.invite.invite',$user, function ($message) use ($email) {
    $message->subject('Message Subject');
    $message->from('noreply@example.net', 'Sender Name');
    $message->to($email); // Recipient address
});
```

but when I add an array I get that error:

```
Mail::send('emails.invite.invite', array('link' => URL::route('account-activate', $code), $user, function ($message) use ($email) {
    $message->subject('Message Subject');
    $message->from('noreply@example.net', 'Sender Name');
    $message->to($email); // Recipient address
});
```

Comment: You are missing one closing bracket `array('link' => URL::route('account-activate', $code)` here .. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($user) {
             Mail::send('emails.invite.invite', array('link' => URL::route('account-activate', $code),'name' => $name), function ($message) use ($email) {
                $message->subject('Message Subject');
                $message->from('noreply@example.net', 'Sender Name');
                $message->to($email); // Recipient address
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your array needs a second close-parantheses:

```
array('link' => URL::route('account-activate', $code))
```

Comment: I added the second parantheses and now get the error "Callback is not valid"

Comment: Do you need to remove $user from the arguments list?  I haven't used Laravel, but the documentation indicates that Mail::send() accepts three parameters: view, data, and options closure.  It looks like you're replacing $user with the explicit array, but $user is still in the arguments list occupying the third slot.  $user is not a function, so I'm guessing that's the source of your invalid callback.

Comment: That was some of the problem, thanks. However, I am having trouble trying to pass a variable in the message->to. In my view I am passing the {{name}} and I am getting undefined variable name. How would I add that to my code for it to work. Pleas see link http://laravel.io/bin/5GJWy

Comment: It's getting beyond my knowledge at this point, having not worked in laravel before.  You'll probably want to complete this question and then post a new one with your updated code, since we've solved the original scope of the question and I'm probably the only person still reading at this point :-)